# Can we use p-values of NIST Test as a score for Randomness for a given binary sequence?

Tags: p-value, randomness

I am given two sequences and the p-values of NIST Tests for both sequences. Can I use these p-values as a measure of the quality of randomness?

Comment: No finite sequence is perfectly random.  You have to decide what properties of randomness you wish to reproduce, and how closely.  The p-values will be related to that but give mixed information, since they also depend on the lengths of the sequences.